# Unresolved reference textView in functions while using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Following tutorial to change set view based on button click.

When I set the variable in onCreate, somehow, I cannot refer to them in functions.

```
abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var count = 0

    fun reset(view: View) {
        count = 0
        textView.setText(count.toString())
    }

    fun plusOne(view: View) {
        count++
        textView.setText(count.toString())
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = "Hello Fam"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a local variable with 'var textView' which is only available in the function onCreate() and is unknown outside of this function. You need to declare the variable outside of onCreate. for example you could write 'lateinit var textView: TextView'

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var textView:TextView
var count = 0

fun reset(view: View) {
count = 0
textView.setText(count.toString())
}

fun plusOne(view: View) {
count++
textView.setText(count.toString())
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
textView.text = "Hello Fam"
}
}
```